# How to set name for asyncio task?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.6

We have a way to set thread name: `thread = threading.Thread(name='Very important thread', target=foo)` and after that get this name for logging purposes with `%(thread)s:` in formatter.
Is it possible to do something like this with `asyncio.Task`?

Comment: Task names are planned for Python 3.8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access the current task with:

```
asyncio.Task.current_task()
```

As any other python object, you can dynamically add some properties to a `Task`.  For example, add this to the first line of any of your coroutines that start a new task:

```
asyncio.Task.current_task().foo = "Bar"
asyncio.Task.current_task().name = "#{}".format(n)
```

Add a [logging filter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) to output this data with your logger.

Comment: Great! I've never even thought about: "Why we need these filters?" :)

Answer (score 10):

As of Python 3.8 you can name your tasks in asyncio

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.set_name

For example:

```
asyncio.create_task(your_coro(), name="your task name")
# or
task = asyncio.create_task(your_coro())
task.set_name("your task name")
```